# Finding a Regular Expression with a Specific Length from a language

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Given this language, I was supposed to find the Regular Expression that represented it. Having given up and getting the answer later (below) I couldn't understand the regular expression.

[image]

Given this answer:

Why is {1,2} and {2} part of the regular expression?

---

EDIT: I dont know if *Understanding Regular Expressions* is a more appropriate title. My issue is that I dont understand the solution for this given problem.

Comment: This regular expression uses an *extended* version of regular expressions where $r\{n,m\}$, for any sub-expression $r$, means $r$ repeated at least $n$ and at most $m$ times. So, for example $(0|1)\{1,2\}$ matches the string $0$, $00$, $1$, $11$, $01$, $10$ and $11$. You can always reduct such an *extended* regular expression to a basic one replacing $e\{n,m\}$ with $\underbrace{e\ldots e}_{\text{$n$ times}}\underbrace{(e(e(...)?)?)?}_{\text{$m-n$ nestings}}$

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $L\{1,2\}$ in this syntax means that the expressions produces words of the form $w$ or $w\cdot v$ for $w,v\in L$. Hence the regular expression you presented produces the empty word ($\epsilon$), all words of length $1$ or $2$ (with $(0\mid 1)\{1,2\}$), and words of length $\geq 3$ with the third character being $0$. Another way to put it, a regular expression that produces the same language with less syntactic sugar is

$$\epsilon + (0+1) + (0+1)(0+1) + (0+1)(0+1)0(0+1)^*$$